# How to use sneaky input with cocos2D 2.0

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

This is my first time using cocos2d for iphone, so right now i consider myself a noobie.

I am trying to use SneakyInput with cocos2D 2.0, but i cant seem to get it to work correctly.

Does anyone know how i can get this up and running? All of the tutorials ive seen seem to be out dated.

Thanks guys

Comment: You can use Kobold2D (www.kobold2d.com) it has SneakyInput already integrated. V2.x uses cocos2d-iphone 2.x. Your issue is probably that not all files are compatible with cocos2d 2.x. You should leave out the non-skinned classes (CircleButton or whatever they're called, those which use OpenGL for rendering their contents).

Answer (score 0):

What is the problem you are facing when you are using SneakyInput? If your cocos2D project is not compiling with the SneakyInput source files, the only reason I can think of is that SneakyInput is not ARC-enabled, otherwise everything should work as like with cocos2d 1.0.

If you are getting ARC related errors, you can select Edit-> Refactor-> Convert to Objective-C ARC from the Xcode Menu, select only your project, then go ahead and convert it to ARC.

Alternatively, you can select your project under Targets, then Build Phases -> Compile Sources, then select the SneakyInput files and add the following flag to each of them:

```
–fobjc-no-arc
```

Hope this helps.